# How do I bundle in ImageMagick's dependencies in a Qt project?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, dependencies, imagemagick

I currently have a C++/QML application that uses ImageMagick to handle large images. I've written it only for Mac. It works fine when I run the program from Qt Creator, or even when I build it for Release and let it rely on weak linking.

I want to share this program with a friend who does not have the Qt libraries or ImageMagick installed. So I've run macdeployqt over the app bundle in a hope it would insert the frameworks required to run the program.

Thankfully that works. The program starts up and runs. However, once ImageMagick kicks in and tries to open a TIFF file, I'm presented with this error from an exception:
    Error: Magick: no decode delegate for this image format 'TIFF'

After some various Google searches, I've only found issues from people who had that error from installing ImageMagick directly and are trying to use it from console. I can use ImageMagick and read TIFFs completely fine UNTIL I run the app after it has been deployed.

I'm guessing my question now is: How can I deploy the required "delegate" for tiff along with my app bundle?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the very same problem when trying to bundle ImageMagick with a C++ command line utility.

Comment: @jtbullitt Unfortunately I never did. As the project was for macOS, I eventually wrote a homebrew script that would install ImageMagick and the Qt program. Sorry I can't help any further.

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad you found a workaround. I eventually did, too. (FWIW, I took the version of  ImageMagick from their website (i.e., _not_ the Homebrew or Macports versions), unzipped it into the directory I wanted, and did a few quick path corrections to the dylibs using `install_name_tool`. Now IM finds the delegates and the dylibs just fine, and it's completely portable for deployment. (FYI: I posted more info at https://stackoverflow.com/q/55754551/5011245 ).)