# How to install ImageMagick portably on macOS when I can't set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Tags: macos, imagemagick, dylib

I am developing a command line utility for macOS (Mojave) that manipulates images using ImageMagick. I want to share it as a standalone app in such a way that others can use it out-of-the-box without having to install any additional dylibs or frameworks. The Homebrew and MacPorts versions of ImageMagick seem to be "hardwired" to the Mac's system directory structure (`/usr/local` and `/opt/local`, respectively) in such a way that it's difficult (impossible?) to put ImageMagick and its delegate libraries into a portable application bundle. So I am instead using the distribution directly from the [ImageMagick website](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx).

I followed the installation instructions on that page and put the ImageMagick folder in my home directory (at `~myname`). As instructed, I did `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Users/myname/ImageMagick-7.0.8/lib/"`. But when I run `magick`, I get an error message:

```
$ ~myname/ImageMagick-7.0.8/bin/magick logo: test.jpg
dyld: Library not loaded: /ImageMagick-7.0.8/lib/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/myname/ImageMagick-7.0.8/bin/magick
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
$
```

Clearly `magick` isn't finding its dylibs, even when I set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` as instructed. It appears, in fact, that I can't even export `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` into the environment:

```
$ export MAGICK_HOME="/Users/myname/ImageMagick-7.0.8"
$ export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$MAGICK_HOME/lib/"
$ echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
/Users/myname/ImageMagick-7.0.8/lib
$ printenv | grep DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
   # (nothing)
$ printenv | grep ImageMagick
MAGICK_HOME=/Users/myname/ImageMagick-7.0.8
$
```

What's going on? How can I make ImageMagick portable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the version of IM currently on the ImageMagick website (version 7.0.8) is for macOS High Sierra. It's therefore not too surprising that you're having trouble installing it on Mojave. (FWIW, the current Homebrew version (IM 7) and MacPorts (IM 6) do, however, work on Mojave. But, like you, I don't know how to make those versions' handling of the delegates truly portable.)

The reason you can't export `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is because of Apple's ["System Integrity Protection" (SIP)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899), which it added to newer versions of macOS (El Capitan and later). By default, SIP prohibits doing things like changing the env variable `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Although [it is possible to disable SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-macos-os-x), Apple does not recommend doing so.

You can, however, modify `magick` and its dylibs manually using `install_name_tool` so that IM 7.0.8 works fine on Mojave. Here's how (in `bash`):

```
# magick: set the correct path to libMagickCore.dylib 
install_name_tool -change \
    /ImageMagick-7.0.8/lib/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.6.dylib \
    @executable_path/../lib/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.6.dylib \
    /Users/myname/ImageMagick-7.0.8/bin/magick

# magick: set the correct path to libMagickWand.dylib 
install_name_tool -change \
    /ImageMagick-7.0.8/lib/libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.6.dylib \
    @executable_path/../lib/libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.6.dylib \
    /Users/myname/ImageMagick-7.0.8/bin/magick

# libMagickWand.dylib: set the correct ID
install_name_tool -id \
    @executable_path/../lib/libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.6.dylib \
    /Users/myname/ImageMagick-7.0.8/lib/libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.6.dylib

# libMagickWand.dylib: set the correct path
install_name_tool -change \
    /ImageMagick-7.0.8/lib/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.6.dylib \
    @executable_path/../lib/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.6.dylib \
    /Users/myname/ImageMagick-7.0.8/lib/libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.6.dylib

# libMagickCore.dylib: set the correct ID
install_name_tool -id \
    @executable_path/../lib/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.6.dylib \
    /Users/myname/ImageMagick-7.0.8/lib/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.6.dylib
```

Now it works:

```
$ /Users/myname/ImageMagick-7.0.8/bin/magick logo: test.jpg
$ open test.jpg
$ # (Preview opens a nice picture of the ImageMagick logo.)
```

This modifies the paths to the dylibs relative to the location of the `magick` command. As long as you keep the directory structure of the ImageMagick folder intact, it should now be completely portable.

You can easily put those five `install_name_tools` commands into a little `bash` script. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue as OP using Mac OS Monterey, and the solution using `install_name_tools` commands did not work for me.  I did modify the library and path names according to my ImageMagick version and install path.

Here's what worked for me:

When I attempt to run `magick` on the command line, a window pops up with a message saying that the program cannot be run because it is from an unidentified developer, with two options to either "Move to Trash" or "Cancel".  However, if I use Finder to navigate to the application in the `bin/` folder and open it by right-clicking, I instead get a window that states the application is from an unidentified developer, and whether to open it?  I then click Yes.

This is not sufficient for running `magick` on the command line because I still get the popup window with "Move to Trash" or "Cancel", but this time for one of the `.dylib` libraries, in my case `libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.8.dylib`.  This could be solved by opening the offending `.dylib` library from Finder in the same manner as opening `magick` earlier, and clicking Yes.  Running `magick` again gives me a different popup window but this time for a different `.dylib`, and after repeating this process twice I'm now able to use the program.